# safely delete a local branch after rebase - replace of git branch --merged

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I had to change the commit message which was in an old commit in order to push it to a remote server. This commit was just on my machine so I could rebase it interactively and then amend it.

I usually delete all my unused local branches after a push to a remote server and for that I often use

```
   git branch --merged
```

to double check which branches I can delete. However this command just goes backwards in the commit history to check which branches are reachable or not. As I did a rebase, the branch I used was not in the output and I was not 100% confident that my last changes were all included after the rebase. It sounds weird, I know.

How can I know which branches I can safely delete after a rebase? Should I worry about this or rebase is safer than I imagine?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't change any file in your rebase, you could check that your history contains the tree of the other branch.

You can get the tree SHA1 of the other branch with

```
git log --pretty=format:%t -n 1 other_branch
```

Then search for it in your history:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%t %ai %s" | grep <tree_SHA1_you_found>
```

If you get something, it means that at this point in your history you had the exact same set of files as you have in the other branch.